# Gulp-Change giving TypeError | React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, gulp, gulp-changed

I'm following a pretty basic tutorial for react to get acquainted with how it functions.  So forgive me if I've missed something obvious.  Part of the beginning of the tutorial was setting up gulp to handle sass files.  So I set up my gulp file, setup my dependencies and tried to save my scss file, unfortunately I got an `TypeError` error and spent about an hour or so trying to overcome it on my own, but couldn't find anything concrete.

I'm running into an issue with gulp-change.  I've gone line by line and ensure that was the line causing the `TypeError` issue. 
**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-change');

/////////////////
// - SCSS / CSS
/////////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){
    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))

    ////////////line creating the error//////////////
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))        
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
});

//detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);
});

//run tasks
gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

**Error Given**

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:59
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.

TypeError: run.call is not a function
    at R:\Documents\Projects\React Goal App\goal-app\node_modules\gulp-change\index.js:31:14
    at wrappedMapper (R:\Documents\Projects\React Goal App\goal-app\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:84:19)
    at Stream.stream.write (R:\Documents\Projects\React Goal App\goal-app\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:96:21)
    at Transform.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Transform.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Transform.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:147:32)
```

**gulp-change index.js**

```
var eventStream = require('event-stream');

module.exports = gulpChange;

function gulpChange(run) {
    return eventStream.map(function(file, done) {
        if (file.isNull()) {
            return done(null, file);
        }
        if (file.isStream()) {
            return done(new PluginError('gulp-change', 'Streaming not supported.'));
        }
        var content = file.contents.toString();
        var ctx = {
            file: file,
            fname: file.history[file.history.length - 1].substr(file.base.length),
            originalContent: content
        };

        function next(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (content) {
                file.contents = new Buffer(content);
            }
            done(null, file);
        }

        if (run.length > 1) {
////////////////line 31 where run is indicated as not a function/////////////
            run.call(ctx, content, next);
        } else {
            next(null, run.call(ctx, content))
        }
    });
}
```

**default.scss file I'm working with**

```
body{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

**Folder Structure for scss/css**

- goal-app (root)

  - src

    - Assets

      - css
      - scss

        - default.scss

Comment: I assume you have some king Uncaught TypeError. Its helpful that you provide exact error you are facing,

Comment: My fault, I didn't copy all the way.  I'll update as soon as I get home this evening.  Thank you for reaching out.

Comment: Added the additional two error lines I previously omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your code correctly then the **run** parameter of **gulpChange** method is same thing you pass to **changed** method in `.pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))` line. That makes the **run** variable to be *string*.

String is not a function but it has length property and that's why `if (run.length > 1) {` line doesn't throw error and is even calculated as *true*.

The used package is gulp-change not gulp-changed as might think. The documentation of gulp-change says that you must pass function as a parameter.

Comment: I had the same train of thought just when looking through things.  However the documentation for gulp-changed shows that string usage is correct
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed

Comment: But that is wrong package. You are using gulp-change not gulp-changed. Correct package is https://github.com/PoliteJS/gulp-change.

Comment: Grateful for your fresh eyes, although thoroughly embarrassed.  Definitely appreciate you.  Would of spent another late night hour troubleshooting the wrong package.